# How To get data from other microservice in ddd?

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design

I have two services `order service` and `Z service` (Z is a hypothetical name). I Have 3 layer in my project (domain, application, infrastructure). The order service has a registration API. The user calls this web service along with a mobile number and other data. In ordering service, in order to receive the Z_ID, this phone number needs to be sent to the order service

[image]

I have a method in infrastructure layer for call Z service. But my question is in which layer should I call this method?

Should it be handled as follows in the application layer:

```
$order = Order::Create($price, $shop);
$Z_id = // call method in infrastructure
$order->setZID($zid);
```

or the domain layer must request to the infrastructure layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem in the following way:

1. Declare domain interface (repository building block)
2. Implement the interface in the infrastructure
3. Use it in your application layer as an ordinary repository building block

It is worth noting that in this approach domain isn't dependent on infrastructure anymore and as a result it gives you significant flexibility - for example it is easier to change microservice or even use DB instead of HTTP call, this attitude is called hexagonal architecture.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you mean to get the receive Z_ID through the application layer and give it to the domain?

Comment: First I create an order without having an `Z_ID` and in the next step I get the `Z_ID` with the help of the infrastructure layer and add it to the order class.

Comment: Yes you can use this repository (that returns Z_ID) in the application layer. That is the reason of application layer - to use domain building blocks. When it comes to your second question - I think it would be better to call method that returns Z_ID first and then just pass it to constructor along with other parameters or encapsulate logic of creating order in some domain factory.